# How to schedule a job in talend

Tags: jobs, talend, schedule

I've got a Talend's project, in the main job some jobs are called, I want to call one of them only if the system time is 14:00.
Any idea about how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay Migua You Can Use RunIf Trigger In Your Job.
to execute Your Job Based on Time You Have to

1. Take One tJava Component in which you have to set current time in globalMap
   -> globalMap.put("TIME", new Date().getHours());
2. draw a runif trigger from tJava Component to Your Subjob
   and write condition in runif
   -> Integer.parseInt(globalMap.get("TIME").toString())==16 (or whatever You want)
   tJava --->IF---->Your Subjob or Your Component

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using system proprietary task scheduler (linux use crontab , windows use task scheduler).

**Windows schedule** - http://etladvisors.com/2014/05/06/windows-deployment-and-scheduling-of-talend-jobs/

**Using linux crontab** - https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-scheduling-jobs-with-cron-crontab-reference.html

If your purpose is a plataform, to conduct the job, see scheduling options, command line, version control, integration with jenkins and others you will need the enterprise subscription version of Talend, which has **TAC** ( Talend Administration Center).